# Nodejs event loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So the async programming in client-side javascript is that the setTimeOut is ran in the browser API so it doesn't block javascript single thread. Since we don't have the browser API in Node, who runs the async part of the code? C or C++?

Comment: Did you read the [docs](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/timers-in-node/#:~:text=setTimeout()%20accepts%20a%20function,myFunc(arg)%20%7B%20console.)?

Comment: API is short for "Application Programming Interface". It is an interface, a set of function declarations that are used by other programs to communicate with the program that provides the API. Many people nowadays use the term API incorrectly. Regarding your question, both the browsers and Node.js provide a JavaScript engine that runs the JavaScript code. Both provide the `setTimeout()` function and both are able to run async code. These engines are written in C and/or C++ but this does not really matter; they could be written in other languages as well.

Answer (score 1):

First off, node.js consists of a runtime environment that includes the V8 Javascript engine, a cross platform library (written in C/C++) that includes the event loop) which is called `libuv` and then a library full of all sorts of add-on functions that are not part of the standard Javascript definition for doing networking, crypto, file system access and so on.  Many of these library functions are written in a combination of Javascript and C++.

The asynchronous operations in node.js are all from the nodejs runtime library written in C/C++.  This includes all sorts of things such as `setTimeout()`, the entire `fs` library for accessing files, the `net` library for doing networking, etc...